# Installing Linux with USB on Mac

Tags: ubuntu, osx

I am trying to get Ubuntu (version 14 I believe. It's the latest version) installed on my Macbook Pro (Late 2013 edition 13 inch, no disk drive in it) via a USB Flashdrive. I have followed every single step at the official Ubuntu installation guide [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx). But on step 3 of this tutorial I end up having `target.img.dmg` instead of `target.img`. Is there a reason as to why this is happening?

Comment: Step 3 says "Note: OS X tends to put the .dmg ending on the output file automatically.", so if you wrote `target.img` then the extra suffix looks like expected behaviour.

Comment: I didn't get it to work alongside with OS X, but I am using a VM for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what Step 3 of link shows, it seems as if this is expected behavior. Maybe they left it out of the screenshot because it just gets appended anyway?

Comment: What do you mean? Whenever I try the 8th step, I get errors. No matter what. Whether I include the .dmg or get rid of it on the file name. I get errors still.

Comment: Didn't know you were getting that far. What is the error at Step 8?

Comment: I was getting an error. I re-ran through the steps and 8 worked. Need to restart.

Comment: Okay. The error I get is that this disk is not readable. Which it should be completely readable.

Comment: Just one last question: did you eject the usb per the instructions? I hear that if you do it wrong it is bad news.

Comment: I followed each step, but when I went to boot up in ubuntu, it just gave me a black screen?